# Finding vector sum from multiple angles.

Tags: vectors, physics

> The two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ in the figure below have equal magnitudes of 14.9 m and their angles are $θ_1 = 30°$ and $θ_2 = 114°$.
>
> [image]

I've tried:

cos30 times 14.9, sin30 times 14.9, then cos114 times 14.9, sin114 times 14.9.

That yielded 12.9i+7.45j, -6.06i + 13.61j.

I tried adding I and J, but it's not working. I don't understand why.

Comment: Shouldn't the angle for $\vec b$ be $114\ \mathbf{+\ 30}$?

Comment: Where does plus 30 come from?

Comment: The angle should be measured from the $x$-axis.  If you look at the picture, $\theta_2$ is measured from vector $\vec a$ which itself has angle $\theta_1$ from the $x$-axis.  So $\vec b$ has an angle, measured from the $x$-axis, of $\theta_2 + \theta_1$.